# Does Akamai resubmit on timeout

Tags: browser, akamai

We have an application that is behind Akamai meaning all traffic goes first to Akamai, then to our web server, then our app server. There are a few URLs that do lengthy updates in our app and can take over 4 minutes depending on what the user submits (yes I know that is horrible but this is legacy code - I did not write it but I have to deal with it). This URL uses a post request rather than a get if that matters. What we noticed was if the URL takes more than 2 minutes we see the URL gets called on our app server every 2 minutes even though the browser itself has just one request in the network tab (same thing happens in both IE11 and chrome 45 so dont think this is a browser issue). So lets say the URL takes 6 minutes we will actually see 3 calls in our access logs.

We contacted Akamai support and they deny that they are causing the issue. They provided their logs which shows 3 calls being sent from their server to ours (each one is exactly 2 minutes apart). So now I need to prove that it is in fact Akamai causing the issue (because tech support does not believe 1+1=2 unless you prove it to them).

I've also tried to debug it with fiddler (an http packet sniffer). I see one request coming from the browser but I do also see a keep alive call every 1 minute in fiddler. I assume this does not mean the browser is resubmitting the request and that this is some http standard to keep the socketed connection alive.

Ive searched the Akamai documentation and Ive searched google but cant find anything referring to this issue. I have 2 questions really:

1). Is there any way that the browser itself is somehow resubmitting the request every 2 minutes even though it only shows 1 request in the network tab (IE11 and chrome would both have to be doing this)

2). Has anyone heard of this issue with Akamai before?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i got everything right from your post but from what i understand it could very well be the edge server going on timeout for the request and attempting to re-send it every couple of minutes, in fact in the metadata configuration the default for http-read should be exactly 120 seconds, you should ask your support to check on this and maybe make a configuration change to support the particular need for a lengthy timeout on that URL.. hope that helps!